# MTOUCHTASK: Error MT2002 updating to unified API Xamarin Forms

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Updating to the unified API is proving to be a total nightmare!

I have used the shared project template to create a new Xamarin forms application and followed the documentation twice and yet both times get the error below

MTOUCHTASK: error MT2002: Failed to resolve "System.Void UIKit.UICollectionView::set_DataSource(UIKit.IUICollectionViewDataSource)" reference from "Xamarin.iOS, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=84e04ff9cfb79065"

This is really getting frustrating now!  Can anyone help please?  I have tried linking all assemblies in the linker options but that makes no difference

I am using version 1.3.1.6294-pre1 of Xamarin forms

Alternatively, how can I get updated versions of the project templates that work with the unified API?

Please note that I am getting these problems using the project template only, i.e. there is none of my own code in this yet

Paul

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same issue (still am). I changed the linker settings to "Don't link" and that temporarily solved the problem. It seems that there are currently bugs in the linker for unified libraries.

Answer (score 1):

@Paul, came across your post searching for a solution to the same problem.  The only thing I can help with is to point you to [this](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/28442/no-xamarin-forms-support-for-ios-unified-apps) post on the Xamarin forums that states that you must enable Alpha channel updates to get the new templates in Xamarin Studio and VS 2013.  The new templates are also available in VS 2015 on the stable channel.  Will monitor this thread for the solution to the other problem!

Comment: I can confirm that the project compiles successfully after enabling the alpha update channel and downloading the latest updates.

Answer (score 0):

When I turned off Linking, my release iPhone config finally built.